# recommendation for clustering algorithm for time-series data

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, cluster-analysis

I am new to cluster analysis and am using the Python sklearn.cluster module to analyze my data.  I am not having any luck so far so I want to ask for a recommendation.  My data consists of event counts on certain dates over a period of a few centuries (more specifically, the number of baptisms, marriages, or burials recorded in church registers).  So my data can actually be represented as a simple vector of integers: [5,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1.....] where every day is represented, but the event count may be zero.  I actually want to identify possible gaps in the record keeping, and I thought that I could cluster the events and then look at the gaps between the clusters.  This isn't as simple as reporting whether the gap between successive dates is above some threshold, because it actually depends on the number of events being recorded per day and the frequency of recording. For example, imagine 30 events per month for a period of years, then just 1 event per week for a period of 3 months, then increasing again to 30 events per month for several years. In that case I would say there could be a gap for the 3 month period where there was a sharp decrease in the number of events, even though there were a few events during that period.  In other words, a "gap" doesn't mean zero events over a long period of time. Rather, it would be indicated by a change in the total count of events over a certain period, relative to the count for a prior period and the subsequent period.

So it seems to be a density-based clustering problem.  I'm going to have clusters of variable density, but I don't know how many there are going to be, so I can't use an algorithm like KMeans that requires you to know how many clusters there are.  I tried HDBSCAN, but it finds clusters that aren't even contiguous in time, that is, cluster 1 consists of a series of dates, then cluster 2, and then back to cluster 1, which makes no sense for my data.  I don't have enough experience to know the strengths, weaknesses, and requirements of the many algorithsm, but I would like a suggestion of what to try from either sklearn, or at least something that is available in python.

Answer (score 0):

An out of the box clustering *cannot* just magically solve your problems. By it's nature, clustering is a *fragile* approach that needs to be carefully guided via appropriate preprocessing.

Here I think you should rather look into **time series segmentation** rather than clustering. Because these methods actually use time information.